# How to change the Inappbrowser back/forward buttons size?

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser, cordova-plugins

I am using a Phonegap app to house a browser shell for a fully responsive website and I tweaked the Inappbrowser on IOS to only show the back/forward buttons but they are ridiculously tiny when I view the app on an actual iPhone. I'm talking like 8px by 4px tiny.

I searched through the CVDInAppBrowser.m file but couldn't find any settings for the actual size of the back/forward buttons.

I'm also having a tough time locating a solution via Google.

Any ideas on how this can achieved?

EDIT - Altering the toolbar height in the CVDInAppBrowser.m made the background container behind the buttons larger which makes the buttons stand out more but they are still so freakin tiny.